# Sending an email from a .Net application to recipients, I want to retrieve the email of the recipient who clicked the link

Tags: .net, email

If I am sending an email from a .Net application to recipient A and recipient B, containing a link to a website. How can I retrieve the email of the recipient who clicked the link, and save it in the Database?

Comment: @LukaszDynowski, changing someone's choice of "I am" vs "I'm" is no different to changing their choice of "colour" to "color", please don't. Both are equally valid! Not only that but it doesn't add to, or in any tangible way improve, the question.

Comment: Good point! Noted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send separate emails; this will not work with one email with multiple recipients.

Generate a random token for each user, and in the email for each user have a link with that token in the querystring. When they follow the link, you can check the querystring in your server and thus find out who clicked on it.